# Motherboard replacement

Tags: laptop

Hey all, so I have an HP dv9700 notebook that apparently has a defective graphics chip. It's all over the net and HP ain't paying for the repair. I'm looking to see if I can get another motherboard to replace it - either the exact same one or a different model that will fit in my chassis. If that's not possible, is there anyway I can utilize the LCD screen? Also, can anyone recommend me a place to get replacement parts? Thanks!

Comment: Purchasing advice is off topic for super user.

Comment: As Daisetsu points out, purchasing advice is off-topic.  Also if you want to know if you can utilize the LCD somehow, you may want to ask that as a separate question, with more specifics on how you want to utilize it.

Answer (score 1):

I would only get a replacement from HP, otherwise consider replacing the Laptop.

To contact HP in North America call 1-866-671-7362 from 6:00 am to 11:00 pm MST, 7 days a week.

Ask them if your Laptop is covered by the Limited Warranty Service Enhancement, if not they will quote you prices for repair.

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ca&docname=c01087277

.